# spring web service client signing with smart card

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have to consume web service and the request have to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pid="http://pid.purs.gov.rs">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <ds:Signature>
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#X509-sertifikatId">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-1">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-sertifikatId"/>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-sertifikatId">...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1">
      ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The whole body part have to be signed.

I found lots of examples but all of them use keystore on local disc and I have to sign message using smart card. As I understood I can export certificate from smart card to .cer file but it won't have private key in it. So is there a way to do this and how?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/), here are examples as good starting point for you problem :

[Link 1](http://sosie2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sosie2/src/org/sosie2/client/authentication/TestX509AndLicenseToken.java)

[Link 2](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/wss4j/tags/1_6_0-alpha/src/test/java/org/apache/ws/security/message/SignaturePartsTest.java)

I know it was helpful to me ;)